# WebView2 return promise from ExecuteScriptAsync

Tags: webview2

Currently the WebView2 API allows us to execute JS in a hosted page by calling the `ExecuteScriptAsync` method. The return type is `Task<string>`. In some of the pages I am trying to integrate the return type from the JS is of `Promise<string>`. Is there any way I can get the result of the resolved promise, or do I need to ensure that the function in my page is synchronous in order to return a result?

Comment: A Promise is a javascript thing, I don't think you can return it.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak, given the similarities to a task in .NET, I was hoping there was some method I am missing that could return it as a .NET task.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no that's not directly supported. You can open a feature request on our [github project](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues). It would be great if we could add support for that.

Currently ExecuteScriptAsync will only give you meaningful return values from the script that is executed synchronously.

As a workaround, you'd need to ExecuteScript to start the asynchronous script execution and then instead of returning the promise in script, use the promise completion to post a message from script to your host app for which you explicitly add a [WebMessageReceived event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webmessagereceived?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll add the request